# How to add a file upload (maybe multile files) option to a form

Tags: php, forms, upload, attachment

I'm not much of a coder, and I'm using this php-script for a contact form, but I want to add a file upload option but I don't know how to.

This is the script so far and that works perfectly for regular messages, but I don't know where and how to add lines for the file upload:

```
<?php

$from = 'SENDER NAME <name@domain.com>';

$sendTo = 'RECEIVER NAME <name@otherdomain.com>';

$subject = 'Subject line';

$fields = array('Name' => 'Name', 'Email' => 'Emailaddres', 'Tel' => 'Phone', 'Subject' => 'Subject', 'Message' => 'Message'); 

$okMessage = 'Message sent!';

$errorMessage = 'Message sent';

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is leeg');

    $emailText = "Pre-text";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

This is the file upload field:

```
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" name="upload" class="custom-file-input" id="upload1">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="upload1"></label>
</div>
```

So  I'm guessing something like 'File' => 'upload1' needs to be added to the array line or isn't it that simple?

Home someone can point me into the right direction.

Comment: $from is declared twice. $from = 'SENDER NAME <name@domain.com>';

$from = 'RECEIVER NAME <name@otherdomain.com>';

Comment: you're right. Made a mistake. Changed it.